# android surfaceview crashes when go to background

Tags: android, surfaceview

my app get crashed when the surfaceview goes to background by recieving call or exit and return to the app. i read that surfacedestroyed doesnt get call on these situations but 
the solutions that were given didnt work for me.
i will be gratefull if someone can help me with my code.
thanks

```
public GameLoopThread(GameView view)
{

this.view=view;
}
public void setRunning (boolean run)
{
    running=run;
}
@Override
public void run() {

    long ticksPerSecond=1000/FPS;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;
    while (running)
    {
        Canvas c=null;
        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
        c=view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
        synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
            view.onDraw(c);
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally{
            if(c!=null)
            view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
        sleepTime=ticksPerSecond-(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
        try
        {if(sleepTime>0)
            sleep(sleepTime);
        else
            sleep(10);

        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            while (!running) {
                try {
                    mPauseLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

and in the surfaceview:
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
 if(gameLoopThread.isAlive())
            {
                boolean retry = true;
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                while (retry) {
                    try {
                        gameLoopThread.join();
                        retry = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                if(!gameLoopThread.isAlive())
                    {           

                     gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                     gameLoopThread.start();

                    }
            }
```

---

maybe the logcat will help:

> 10-22 09:35:06.310: DEBUG/Buddies--------------------------->(10985): Service:OnReceive ACTION_HOME_RESUME called
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3275): Shutting down VM
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: WARN/dalvikvm(3275): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at tomer.idunku3.GameView$1.surfaceDestroyed(GameView.java:126)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.view.SurfaceView.reportSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceView.java:613)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:498)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:407)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:217)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:4080)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:720)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:720)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:790)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1868)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
>   10-22 09:35:06.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3275):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-22 09:35:06.320: ERROR/(18080): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error

Comment: thanks but no. now when i hit home button after a few seconds my app is getting crashed. any other ideas?

Comment: So when you press home button, you want to destroy the surfaceview? Is this what you're asking?

Comment: no. i want the game to continue run in the background and be able to return to it as any other app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think this part is necessary:

```
synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        while (!running) {
            try {
                mPauseLock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

If you use this, you'll need to notify in order to release the lock on wait();
But try using the same code, with out the synchronized(mPauseLock)

EDIT:

The solution for your problem when you press on the Home button, the application crashes, do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameView = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameView); 
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    gameView.gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
    finish();
}
```

And in GameView (SurfaceView) create the constructor:

```
public GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help.i saw your edit now. this end the app nicely without crashing, but the state of the gamed isn't saved. any ideas for that?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state

Answer (score 3):

My application randomly (pretty often) crashed when returning to previous activity.
Turns out the "try" statement is not working as expected as Canvas c can be null still after the getHolder() method.

```
while (running) {
    Canvas c=null;
    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        c=view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
        if(c!=null){ // <- this is the line of code I had to add to make it work
            synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                view.onDraw(c);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    finally{
        if(c!=null)
        view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: I had a working game, but after refactoring it I had a problem resuming it. I could either resume the surfaceview after running an activity on top of it or have it work properly after pressing and resuming from home. The crash after pressing HOME was partially fixed due to your advice of checking if c wasn't null. So, thanks!